# Failed to load '' as a plugin, Jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Im trying to run a **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/962/)** sample with jquery and continue getting this error.

> Failed to load '' as plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".address_field").each(function(index){  
    var widget = new AddressFinder.Widget(this, "WR3NUKVGC4Q97FPHBJXL");
  });
});
```

Im using google Chrome.

Comment: I cannot reproduce in Chrome at that same URL. Are you or some proxy maybe blocking a script from downloading?

Comment: @Jacob only windows firewall not proxy. Behind a wireless router

Comment: @jacob maybe Im doing it wrong, can you prepare a basic jquery fiddle  for me just to be sure?